# ng --version shows Angular CLI: 1.5.4 even after upgrade

Tags: angular-cli

I am trying to upgrade my node to latest 10 version.  I also try to upgrade angular-cli using the steps below:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

However when I check the version using `ng --version`, I still get 1.5.4:

```
Angular CLI: 1.5.4
Node: 10.12.0
OS: darwin x64
```

I'm confused, the latest angular-cli version is 7, but it's still showing 1.5.4.  Please advise.

Comment: I have had a little trouble with using `@latest` in the past also. Try using `npm install -g @angular/cli@7.0.1`

Comment: I would try blowing it all way again. `1. npm uninstall -g angular-cli`, `2. npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`, `3. npm cache clean`, `4. npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`, `5. ng update`

Comment: It looks like up may be running `ng -v` in a directory of an ng application that uses cli version 1.5.4, which will show the local version being used, and not the global. What do you see if you run `ng -v` in a directory where there is no ng application?

Comment: i actually was running ng -v outside my application directory.  that's why it's strange.